# VS code not hot reloading for Flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi i am using Visual Studio with flutter and i am having issues with the hot reload and hot restart.

1.For hot reload its not working at all, on the bottom right corner it shows "syncing files with android x86..." but after a second it disappears but nothing changes on the emulator. 
2. For hot restart its taking alot of time on the first attempt but for the rest of the time it works fine.

  -

What i tried to fix it: 
Looked on stackOverflow and github for similar issues and tried their fixes which were:
- Deleting and downloading a newer version of VS code
- Downgrading to VS code 3.1. 
- Switching to master channel

Nothing seemed to fix the issue so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter doctor` to fix the issue. If it can't detect the emulator, restart your `VS Code` and your emulator.

Comment: with   1 available connected device

Comment: If so, try restarting your device

Comment: i tried closing , deleting the emulator and downloading a new one but still the same issue i verified the emulator's path and it's set in the proper file.